# Dictionary sub sort

Tags: c#, sorting, dictionary

My Dictionary object:

```
Apple, 3
Orange, 6
Lemon, 4
Veggies, 6
Banana, 4
Squash, 7
```

My current code sorts by Value:

```
 var items = from pair in dict
      orderby pair.Value descending
      select pair;
```

I would like to sort descending on Value(int) first and sub-sort ascending on Key(string), example:

```
 Squash, 7
 Orange, 6
 Veggies, 6
 Banana, 4
 Lemon, 4
 Apple, 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add additional ordering conditions by means of ',' separators:

```
var items = 
  from pair in dict 
  orderby pair.Value descending, pair.Key 
  select pair;
```

Comment: Thank you.  I appreciate your sharpness.  My sharpness is diminishing after too many sleepless nights on my project.